# How to do standalone on-the-fly in-memory compilation with the eclipse compiler?

Tags: java, eclipse

The eclipse compiler and its API have some significant advantages (especially beneficial to my application) over the one included in the JDK and so I'd like to use it. I have a standalone utility and I want to minimize its size and dependencies.

What is the way to get access to the eclipse compiler (minimum set of jar files and where to download them) and compile generated code on the fly in memory?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but it was the first hit I got from googling "eclipse compiler": http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php

Comment: That's kind of what I'm talking about but notice that is much more than just the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download ECJ by [starting from this page](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/), clicking on the latest release, then find and download the file ecj-[version].jar. For this, I’m using 4.2.1. Reference this jar in your classpath.

You use the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler`. Most things for the constructor have defaults available. You just give it a callback for the results in the form of an ICompilerRequestor. The below example uses a simple byte class loader to test the results. To do cascading compilation, you create a subclass of FileSystem, overriding the methods from INameEnvironment.

```
package test.eclipse.compiler;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ClassFile;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.DefaultErrorHandlingPolicies;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ICompilerRequestor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.FileSystem;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.FileSystem.Classpath;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.env.INameEnvironment;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.impl.CompilerOptions;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.problem.DefaultProblemFactory;
import org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.Util;


public class TestCompile {
    static class ByteClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        private Map<String, byte[]> classMap;


        public ByteClassLoader(Map<String, byte[]> classMap) {
            super();
            this.classMap = classMap;
        }

        protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            byte[] bytes = classMap.get(name);
            if (bytes == null) {
                return super.findClass(name);
            } else {
                return defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void compile(String code, String filename) {
        ArrayList<Classpath> cp = new ArrayList<FileSystem.Classpath>();
        Util.collectRunningVMBootclasspath(cp);
        INameEnvironment env = new NameEnv(cp.toArray(new FileSystem.Classpath[cp.size()]), null);
        ICompilerRequestor requestor = new ICompilerRequestor() {
            @Override
            public void acceptResult(CompilationResult result) {
                ClassFile[] cf = result.getClassFiles();
                HashMap<String, byte[]> classMap = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();
                classMap.put("Test", cf[0].getBytes());
                ByteClassLoader cl = new ByteClassLoader(classMap);
                try {
                    Class<?> c = cl.loadClass("Test");
                    Method m = c.getMethod("test");
                    m.invoke(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Compiler compiler = new Compiler(env, DefaultErrorHandlingPolicies.exitAfterAllProblems(),
                new CompilerOptions(), requestor, new DefaultProblemFactory());

        ICompilationUnit[] units = new ICompilationUnit[] { new CompilationUnit(code.toCharArray(), filename, null) };
        compiler.compile(units);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        compile("public class Test { public static void test() { System.out.println(\"Hello, world.\"); }}",
                "Test.java");
    }
}
```

Copied with permission from [this blog post](http://mentics.com/compiling-on-the-fly-with-the-eclipse-compiler/)

Comment: The NameEnv class is missing. I found this (https://github.com/mentics/shen-on-java/blob/master/Shen-on-Java/src/main/java/com/mentics/ecj/NameEnv.java) but it has a bunch of dependencies on other parts of the app. Do you have a simple implementation of it that does the bare necessities?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can find what you're looking for in [the maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj/) and [use it](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/) with [ant](http://ant.apache.org) pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks! Is there somewhere that tells how to use it to compile a single class in memory? I'll more clearly indicate that in the question.

Comment: I'd write the string to a file ending in .java and send that to ECJ.

Comment: No. This is a performance critical situation. Needs to be as fast as possible.